# ESP32: When to use nvs_flash_init?

Tags: esp32

When I use esp-idf. All the examples that use the WiFi library call the nvs_flash_init function. Why? Is this necessary because the WiFi library uses encrypted data?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are we talking ESP-IDF, Arduino, MicroPython, CircuitPython, Espruino, LUA...? There are dozens of WiFi libraries out there in multiple software platforms.

Comment: Sorry. I am code with ESP-IDF.

Answer (score 0):

The Wifi library uses NVS flash to store access point name and password

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).